# Iterar en las líneas de una columna de un marco de datos y escribir en otra

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Tengo un dataframe y para cada línea en la coumna `QType`, si está marcada como `section`, quiero poner el contenido de la columna de preguntas en la (nueva) columna `Section`, hasta la próxima vez que encuentre `section` en `QType`. Aqui esta la dataframe:

```
>>> df[['Questions','QType']].head(10)
                                           Questions            QType
0    When do you think your next vacation can start?  Multiple Choice
1  What are your preferences regarding medical tr...  Multiple Choice
2  What is your preferences of complementary brea...  Multiple Choice
3  What is your preference for a in-hotel grocery...     Likert Scale
4                               Consumer Personality          Section
5         What is your preference of hotel check-in?  Multiple Choice
6  What is your preference of payment during Chec...  Multiple Choice
7  What is your preference of hotel cancellation ...  Multiple Choice
8       Boooooooooooooooooooooo                       Multiple Choice
9  What is your preference of the concierge service?  Multiple Choice
```

Y me gustaria una cosa como:

```
>>> df[['Questions','QType']].head(10)
                                           Questions            QType    Section
0    When do you think your next vacation can start?  Multiple Choice    None
1  What are your preferences regarding medical tr...  Multiple Choice    None
2  What is your preferences of complementary brea...  Multiple Choice    None
3  What is your preference for a in-hotel grocery...     Likert Scale    None
5         What is your preference of hotel check-in?  Multiple Choice    Consumer Personality
6  What is your preference of payment during Chec...  Multiple Choice    Consumer Personality
7  What is your preference of hotel cancellation ...  Multiple Choice    Consumer Personality
9  What is your preference of the concierge service?  Multiple Choice    Booooooooooooooooooooo
```

Hasta hoy intenté:

```
>>> section = None
>>> for i, row in df.iterrows():
...     if df.loc[i, 'QType'] == 'Section':
...         section = df.loc[i,'Questions']
...     df.loc[i,'Section']=section
...
```

Y obtengo:

```
>>> df[['Questions','QType','Section']].head(10)
                                           Questions            QType               Section
0    When do you think your next vacation can start?  Multiple Choice                   NaN
1  What are your preferences regarding medical tr...  Multiple Choice                   NaN
2  What is your preferences of complementary brea...  Multiple Choice                   NaN
3  What is your preference for a in-hotel grocery...     Likert Scale                   NaN
4                               Consumer Personality          Section  Consumer Personality
5         What is your preference of hotel check-in?  Multiple Choice  Consumer Personality
6  What is your preference of payment during Chec...  Multiple Choice  Consumer Personality
7  What is your preference of hotel cancellation ...  Multiple Choice  Consumer Personality
8       What is your preference of the guest policy?  Multiple Choice  Consumer Personality
```

Solo necesito deshacerme con las lineas que tienen en 'Questions' el nombre de la 'Section' como la liea 5

Comment: Si lo que haces te da en `NaN` en los espacios que quieres `None`, es tan fácil como `df.fillna(None)`, no sé si eso te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Para eliminar aquellas filas donde el valor de **Questions** es igual al valor de **Section**, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```py
# Obtener los índices de las filas a eliminar
i = df[df["Questions"] == df["Section"]].index

# Eliminar las filas
df.drop(index=i, inplace=True)

# Restablecer los índices del dataframe para
# que sean números consecutivos a partir de 0
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```